# When should you call it PCoA vs. PCA

Tags: pca, terminology, multidimensional-scaling

I'm reviewing a paper. In it the authors use a genetic distance metric to created a distance matrix between subjects, then they run classic MDS on this distance matrix.  Throughout the MS they call this a principal components analysis (PCA).  I was trained to call this principal coordinates analysis (PCoA) or classic Torgerson's multidimensional scaling.  Can anyone clarify which terms are correct, and if more than one, which is preferred?

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14002/whats-the-difference-between-principal-components-analysis-and-multidimensional

Comment: In PCA, you usually have a objects by variables dataset as the input. In PCoA, the input is a square distance matrix.This is their difference. Main math operations and theory behind both are essentially the same.