# Representing experimental data by unconstrained ordination: PCA, PCoA, or NMDS?

Tags: r, pca, multidimensional-scaling, ecology, pcoa

I have a dataset composed by presence of different bacterial families in function at different pesticide treatment. I need to find a good representation of my data but I don't know which method (**Principal Component analysis** or **Principal Coordinate analysis** or **Nonmetric Multidimensional Scaling**) is better for species' abundance data.

Comment: In answers to [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14002/3277) question it has been shown that PCoA _is_ fundamentally PCA. When we use PCA approach in order to map in low dimension a matrix of distances between observations (rather than observations X variables data) we call it PCoA. Iterative forms of MDS (not necessarily nonmetric, NMDS) are more advanced tools to do the task: they can map the distances with less error (loss) and they have more options, such as selecting the loss function, for example.

Comment: It has also been shown that NMDS is better for zero-rich species abundance matrices because it has fewer assumptions. It is not clear, though, where the pesticide treatment comes into your question as currently worded.