# Alternative to PCA that maintains densities/distances

Tags: pca, unsupervised-learning, tsne

The question is the same as posed in the title; is there an alternative to PCA that doesn't rely on the linear assumption but maintains distances (i.e. the main issue with UMAP/tSNE)?

Thanks!

Comment: what you mean with "preserves distances"? that two points far 2 units one domain, should be far 2 in the second domain?... AFAIK, PCA preserves only "far" distances

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia The phrasing "preserves distances" is a common synonym for ["isometry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry). I am not aware of any other meaning.

Comment: @Galen I'm referring to this (eg) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176672/what-is-meant-by-pca-preserving-only-large-pairwise-distances

Comment: also, non linear mapping usually has not closed form solution, and thus you can non linear autoencoders (idk about this isometry property though)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Interesting. Sort of a loose phrasing of "preserving", but I can imagine there being an asymptotic result applying to this.

Comment: Maybe a better way to phrase it is that I would like to know which features contribute to the differences in classes more than the non-important ones... like a ranking. For example in PCA I can check the variance contributed by each feature