# Does it makes sense to perform MDS when $n<p$?

Tags: multidimensional-scaling

According to the reference quoted below, when performing a classical MDS on a dataset, I have to compute a centered matrix $B$ based on the dissimilarity matrix and then to compute the eigen-decomposition $B = V \Lambda V^T$.

Then it is said (top page 320, step 4),

> If the points were originally in a $p$-dimensional space, the first $p$ eigenvalues of $B$ are nonzero and the remaining $n-p$ are zero.

**But what if $n<p$? Does it even have sense to try it?**

And what does it mean to "discard the 0 eigenvalues from $\Lambda$"? Replace 0 by 0?

Reference :

- [COX T. F., COX M. : *Multidimensional Scaling*. In Handbook of Data Visualisation, Chen C.-h., Härdle W., Unwin A., (Eds.). Springer, 2008, ch. III.3, pp. 315–347.](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-33037-0_14)

Comment: `But what about if n<p?` N points can span at most n dimensions in euclidean space; so, the maximum for p is n itself. Another thing is that you initially might have had nXp data with p _features_ > n points, it is possible. But is such a case, when you compute nXn distances the maximal intrinsic _dimensionality_ will be n, not p.

Comment: ...and when the space origin is the centroid of the points cloud, as it with the matrix B (the double-centration matrix), the maximal possible dimensionality is n-1.

Comment: Thank you ! And what about discarding eigenvalues ? Does it mean create a new matrix of size $n \times p$ ?

Comment: On this [thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14002/3277), pay attention to my as well as amoeba's answers. In particular, my answer links to a short a easy document with formulas describing Torgerson's MDS.