# How does Principal Coordinate Analysis (PCoA) work, as compared to PCA?

Tags: pca, python, dimensionality-reduction, linear-algebra, pcoa

I am familiar with `PCA` from [Making sense of principal component analysis, eigenvectors & eigenvalues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues) where you either normalize the data (to standard normal or centered?) and construct a covariance matrix or just construct the correlation matrix, eigendecomposition, sort eigenvalue/vector pairs by eigenvalue in descending order (the ratio of these eigenvalues to their sum is the `explained variance`), and finally, transform the original data to be projected onto the new eigenvalue axes `matmul(X, sorted_eigenvectors.T)`

This makes sense to me but **WHAT IS PRINCIPAL COORDINATE ANALYSIS?**  I understand you use a distance matrix instead of a correlation matrix.  What does this mean in terms of eigenvectors?  In PCA, the eigenvectors are in the direction of maximum variance but what about in a distance matrix space?

Here's some `Python 3` code I made to do PCA.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import decomposition

np.random.seed(0)

# Iris dataset
DF_data = pd.DataFrame(load_iris().data, 
                       index = ["iris_%d" % i for i in range(load_iris().data.shape[0])],
                       columns = load_iris().feature_names)

Se_targets = pd.Series(load_iris().target, 
                       index = ["iris_%d" % i for i in range(load_iris().data.shape[0])], 
                       name = "Species")

# Correlation matrix (Note: StandardScaler of data and then covariance = correlation)
DF_corr = pd.DataFrame(np.corrcoef(DF_data.T), 
                      index = DF_data.columns,
                      columns = DF_data.columns)

# Eigendecomposition
Ve_eig_vals, Ar_eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(DF_corr)

# Sorting eigenpairs
eig_pairs = [(np.fabs(Ve_eig_vals[j]), Ar_eig_vecs[:,j]) for j in range(DF_data.shape[1])]
eig_pairs.sort(); eig_pairs.reverse()
Ar_components = np.array([x[1] for x in eig_pairs])

# Projection matrix
Ar_Wproj = np.array([x[1] for x in eig_pairs]).T

DF_transformed = pd.DataFrame(np.matmul(DF_data.as_matrix(),Ar_Wproj),
                              columns=["PC_%d" % k for k in range(1, Ar_Wproj.shape[1]+1)])
#          PC_1      PC_2      PC_3      PC_4
# 0    2.669231 -5.180887 -2.506061 -0.115201
# 1    2.696434 -4.643645 -2.482874 -0.105533
# 2    2.481163 -4.752183 -2.304354 -0.102643
# 3    2.571512 -4.626615 -2.228277 -0.276660
# 4    2.590658 -5.236211 -2.409756 -0.153814
# 5    3.008099 -5.682217 -2.456525 -0.221893
# 6    2.490942 -4.908714 -2.106376 -0.181431
# 7    2.701455 -5.053209 -2.444074 -0.209103
```

Can I literally just replace the correlation matrix (`DF_corr`) w/ a distance matrix?

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

Ar_MxMdistance = distance.squareform(distance.pdist(DF_data.T, metric="braycurtis"))
DF_dism = pd.DataFrame(Ar_MxMdistance, index = DF_data.columns, columns = DF_data.columns)
```

Comment: PCoA, aka Torgerson's metric MDS, is quite transparently described in some answers to [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14002/3277). I even tend to consider your question as a duplicate to it. Both @amoeba and me have explained there how PCoA is actually a PCA in its core. For example, in my answer find link to a document describing PCoA's math and link to an answer explaining "double centration" which is a switch from distances to scalar products of a centered "Gram matrix". The coordinates yielded by PCoA are actually "loadings" of the PCA performed on that matrix.

Comment: What do you get when you do eigendecomposition on a distance matrix?

Comment: PCoA does not do eigendecomposition of a distance matrix.