# Can I rotate a (classical) MDS result with varimax etc.?

Tags: pca, similarities, multidimensional-scaling, factor-rotation, pcoa

I have a matrix of (scaled) co-occurence counts which I would like to summarise using (classical, i.e. PCA-related) Multi-Dimensional Scaling (MDS), and **then rotate** (with `varimax()`, `quartimax()`, or really *any* other optimisation routine).

Let `Azra` be the matrix of (scaled) co-occurence counts:

```
Azra <- structure(c(1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 
0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 1, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.111111111111111, 0.277777777777778, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
1, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.333333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.277777777777778, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 
0.222222222222222, 0.277777777777778, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 
0.166666666666667, 1, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 
0.333333333333333, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.222222222222222, 
0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 
0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 0.277777777777778, 0.388888888888889, 
0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0, 
0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 1, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.388888888888889, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 
0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.277777777777778, 
0.444444444444444, 0.277777777777778, 0.388888888888889, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 1, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 1, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.277777777777778, 0.333333333333333, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.388888888888889, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 1, 0.111111111111111, 0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 
0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 0.333333333333333, 
0.277777777777778, 0.333333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
1, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.111111111111111, 1, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.222222222222222, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 1, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
1, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 1, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.222222222222222, 0.277777777777778, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 1, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.277777777777778, 0.388888888888889, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 0.444444444444444, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 
0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 
0.222222222222222, 1, 0.277777777777778, 0.388888888888889, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.277777777777778, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.277777777777778, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.277777777777778, 1, 0.277777777777778, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.277777777777778, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.388888888888889, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.388888888888889, 
0.277777777777778, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
1, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 1), .Dim = c(35L, 
35L), .Dimnames = structure(list(items = c("but-how", "encyclopedia", 
"alien", "language-of-bees", "bad-hen", "correspondence", "bamboozable", 
"inventions", "gray-hair", "i-we", "the-same", "the-better", 
"cockatoo", "caravan", "comma", "headturner", "crocodile", "countries", 
"level", "morning", "idiom", "lullaby", "riddle", "eating-grandpa", 
"easter-bunny", "alphabet-of-swearing", "guilt", "trouble", "eating-animals", 
"random-poetry", "comparatively", "one-letter", "resistance", 
"conjugation", "censored"), items = c("but-how", "encyclopedia", 
"alien", "language-of-bees", "bad-hen", "correspondence", "bamboozable", 
"inventions", "gray-hair", "i-we", "the-same", "the-better", 
"cockatoo", "caravan", "comma", "headturner", "crocodile", "countries", 
"level", "morning", "idiom", "lullaby", "riddle", "eating-grandpa", 
"easter-bunny", "alphabet-of-swearing", "guilt", "trouble", "eating-animals", 
"random-poetry", "comparatively", "one-letter", "resistance", 
"conjugation", "censored")), .Names = c("items", "items")))
```

I first calculate a *distance* matrix as per [this recommendation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36152/converting-similarity-matrix-to-euclidean-distance-matrix).
Then I plug that into *classical* MDS aka. *Principal Coordinates Analysis* (PCoA) aka. *Torgerson's* MDS which, I understand, [is basically a Principal Components Analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14002/whats-the-difference-between-principal-component-analysis-and-multidimensional), only based on Euclidian distances, not correlations or covariances.
Then we plot the results in slices (because we MDS on 3 dimensions), just for kicks and giggles.

```
distances <- sqrt(1-Azra)
md_scaled <- cmdscale(d = distances, k = 3, eig = TRUE)
md_scaled <- as.data.frame(md_scaled)
g1 <- ggplot(data = md_scaled, mapping = aes(x = V1, y = V2, label = rownames(md_scaled))) + geom_text()
g2 <- ggplot(data = md_scaled, mapping = aes(x = V1, y = V3, label = rownames(md_scaled))) + geom_text()
g3 <- ggplot(data = md_scaled, mapping = aes(x = V2, y = V3, label = rownames(md_scaled))) + geom_text()
grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, ncol = 2)
```

[image: slices]

So far so good.

Can I now **rotate the resulting matrix as I would rotate a loadings matrix from a PCA?**

---

It sure is technically possible to rotate and MDS result with `varimax()` and the results *are* different:

```
any(varimax(as.matrix(md_scaled))$loadings == as.matrix(md_scaled))

#> [1] FALSE
```

Anyway, **can I just rotate the results from this MDS as I please**?

Comment: ??? Are you @maxheld?

Comment: nope, but we are working on this problem together. Hope, this question is sufficiently different. I'm new to this, obviously...